# How make git repo install with `go install` command and retract mistakenly published pkg.go.dev package?

Tags: go

I have a small [package](https://github.com/asolopovas/dsync) which has main.go and go.mod in root directory and couple of files in `src/*`, files inside `src` contain `package name` on all files:

Here is the contents of main.go:

```
package main

import (
    package_name "github.com/user/package/src"
)

func main() {
    package_name.Run()
}
```

Here is go.mod:

```
module github.com/user/package

go 1.20
```

I am trying to mimic structure of https://github.com/junegunn/fzf. But in my case whenever I try to do `go install github.com/user/package@latest` I get an error `package github.com/user/package is not a main package` same does not happen with fzf can you please explain my why?

Comment: You have a tag named `latest`. Remove it and try again.

Comment: Same Thing. I removed the tag but I thought that tags were ment to use to guide which version to install?

Comment: See [Version queries](https://go.dev/ref/mod#version-queries) from the "Go Modules Reference".

Comment: latest points automatically to the latest release (of that major version), when using the go cli. Even github redirects to the latest release when asking for latest https://github.com/asolopovas/dsync/releases/latest

Answer (score 1):

According to https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/asolopovas/dsync?tab=versions, you have published `v1.0.0` before. Run `go install` with the `-x` option confirms that:

```
$ go clean -modcache
$ go install -x github.com/asolopovas/dsync@latest
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/@v/list
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/asolopovas/@v/list
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/asolopovas/dsync/@v/list
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/asolopovas/dsync/@v/list: 200 OK (1.202s)
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/@v/list: 404 Not Found (1.202s)
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/asolopovas/@v/list: 404 Not Found (1.202s)
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/asolopovas/dsync/@v/v1.0.0.info
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/asolopovas/dsync/@v/v1.0.0.info: 200 OK (0.293s)
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/asolopovas/dsync/@v/v1.0.0.mod
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/asolopovas/dsync/@v/v1.0.0.mod: 200 OK (0.617s)
# get https://proxy.golang.org/sumdb/sum.golang.org/supported
# get https://proxy.golang.org/sumdb/sum.golang.org/supported: 404 Not Found (0.304s)
# <output truncated>
go: downloading github.com/asolopovas/dsync v1.0.0
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/asolopovas/dsync/@v/v1.0.0.zip
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/asolopovas/dsync/@v/v1.0.0.zip: 200 OK (0.324s)
package github.com/asolopovas/dsync is not a main package
```

Download `https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/asolopovas/dsync/@v/v1.0.0.zip` and check its content. Indeed the package `github.com/asolopovas/dsync` at `v1.0.0` is not a main package.

Now you have updated the `master` branch to turn it into a main package, tag a new version (such as `v1.1.0`) and try again. Hopefully `go install github.com/asolopovas/dsync@latest` should work now.

Comment: Is there a way to reset index on pkg.gov.dev so that its same as in the repo?

Comment: According to the "Removing a package" section in https://pkg.go.dev/about, it can not be reset.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by reading [docs](https://go.dev/blog/go116-module-changes#module-retraction), adding retraction attribute to my `go.mod` file, and creating new tag v1.0.1 (tags like v1.1 did not work, so i had to choose v1.0.1 format) as was suggested by Zeke Lu, then I visited https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/username/package@v1.0.1 and clicked request and overnight I have a new version of the package which works with `go install` command.

go.mod

```
module github.com/asolopovas/dsync

go 1.20

retract (
    v1.0.0 // Published accidentally.
    v0.1.0 // Published accidentally.
)
```